# Power BI Report Server Paginated Report Issue

Tags: parameters, powerbi, report

Having upgraded to 'Version 1.6.7327.3007 (January 2020)' of Power BI Report Server (PBIRS) we are seeing the following error in some report server paginated reports.

An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for dataset 'DefaultSession'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
Incorrect syntax near 'Spec'.

I have isolated this back to an issue in the Multi-value text parameter which is being used to populate the query for the core data set.

The core data set for the report is a SQL SELECT WHERE column in (@parameter)

The text values in the parameter include spaces and dashes and this appears to be part of the issue.

I have installed a copy of the September PBIRS release and copied the same report to that server - it is functioning correctly.

Is anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 0):

For info this was corrected in a later release of PowerBI - we are no longer experiencing the problem